# What are the privacy implications of multsig wallets if one half is compromised?

Tags: multi-signature, privacy

I am trying to work out the privacy implications of the following scenario. Alice and Bob have a multisig wallet together (say Electrum but it doesn't really matter). Alice's computer is somehow compromised and the attackers gain full access to her Electrum wallet so as they have access to the private keys, the master key, the whole works. What are the privacy implications for Bob in this situation? How much information would the attacker be able to derive about Bob from having full access to Alice's wallet?

Edit: just for clarification, I'm not asking about the security implications (for example where they impersonate Alice and get Bob to sign a transaction). Assume for the sake of the question that Bob knows Alice's computer has been compromised. I'm only trying to figure out what information can be derived about/to identify Bob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alice has Bob's xpub in the wallet. She needs this to be able to generate multisig addresses.

If Alice is compromised, full TX history of Alice & Bob will be compromised, and attacker will be also learn about unused addresses or any current UTXOs.

With the xpub, he needs [any 1 secret key from Bob and he could crack the xpriv](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63554/if-a-single-private-key-of-the-hd-bitcoin-account-is-compromised-is-the-whole-h/63603#63603).